# changing iframe height to fit animated content

Tags: jquery, animation, iframe, height

I have some content in an iframe, but the content on click will change height with an animation. I need to change the iframe's height to match the new animation height, how would this be done?

http://www.klossal.com/b_iframe.html

you can see the set up there that isn't working, you click one of the names and you'll see the animation.

Answer (score 1):

You can the function from parent document with JS just define a function in the parent node and call it like this;

```
parent.setIFrameHeight(newValue);
```

and your `setIFrameHeight` function should be like this;

```
function setIFrameHeight(value) {
   document.getElementById("iframe").height = value + "px";
}
```

Comment: FYI this will only work if the iframe conforms with the same origin policy. This technique couldn't be used if the iframe was being embedded in another page which didn't have the same scheme or host as the caller.

Comment: it's the same domain, but same question as the one asked below, how would you get it to animate when you click the content in teh iframe? Is there a way you can add the iframe height changes in the site that's being shown in the frame? They're part of the same domain?

Comment: Check the example http://jsfiddle.net/e4K7Q/. You must just call the Resize function from iframe document as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library to do that and even animate the event easily.

a simple jQuery example example:

HTML:

```
<iframe id="iframe-box" src="httml://jsfiddle.com" height="100px" width="50px"></iframe>   

<div id="clickme" >
  click me
</div>​
```

Javascript

```
$(function(){
    $('#clickme').click(function(){
      $('#iframe-box').animate({'width':'200'})  
    })
});​
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/b6qfJ/)

**Update**

If you wish to access the content inside the iframe, you can also do it with jQuery and the `content()` function:

```
jQueryObject = $("#iframe-box").contents().find("#somecontent")
```

Comment: so how would you get it to animate when you click the content in teh iframe?  Is there a way you can add the iframe height changes in the site that's being shown in the frame?  They're part of the same domain?

Comment: Im not totally sure i understood your question comment, but let me know if the expanded post help you out.